How to find out if Water Droplet will peneatrate Water Umbrella?
Imagine a scenario. we are pouring water from sink on the spoon, because of that some kind of water umbrella is created by water.
Like in this video: https://www.jsme-fed.org/experiment-e/2017_6/001.html?fbclid=IwZXh0bgNhZW0CMTAAAR3SxEKrLUxFkX7iFm6kDBgG9hO1CDGh80F-bRR-GAfeZvxCyeBcOFLeBN8_aem_cPETE5FHcAgr8yuhcpBzDQ
Well i wondered if i artifically drop the water droplet on that umbrella, how can i determine theoretically if it will pass through the water umbrella or not?

https://youtu.be/CwFRJ7SkYvI
